# show that the system has a limit cycle using a theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the following system, and I'm trying to use a theorem to prove that it has a limit cycle. I proceeded finding the fixed points(Strogatz), $(0,0)$ in this case and then calculating the eigenvalues I got the hint that for values of $b, k, m$ such that $b^2<4km$ there might be a limit cycle. I don't really know how  I can prove this using Poincaré-Bendixson given that the old trick of converting to polar coordinates doesn't seem that easy to do here. Can anyone advise me how to proceed here? Thanks.
$$\text{System:}\\ \dot x_1 = x_2 \\ \dot x_2 = \frac{-k}{m}x_1-\frac{b}{m}x_2(x_1^2-1)\\
$$
This is what I've done so far using Poincaré-Bendixson:
$$
\text{Having:} \quad V(x,y) = x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq c
$$
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1} \dot x_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2} \dot x_2 = 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2[\frac{-k}{m}x_1-\frac{b}{m}x_2(x_1^2-1)]\\
=2x_1x_2 -\frac{2k}{m}x_1x_2-\frac{2b}{m}x_2^2x_1^2  + \frac{2b}{m}x_2^2\\
\text{using k,m as 1 and b as 0.1, I got:}\\
=2x_1x_2 -2x_1x_2-0.2x_1^2x_2^2  + 0.2x_2^2\\
=0.2(-x_1^2x_2^2+x_2^2) 
$$

Comment: See Vander Pol oscillator, Liénard systems, fast-slow systems, canard solutions. There is no easy nice Lyapunov function.

Comment: Can you suggest me another way to do it then?

Comment: You could try and see if there is a Hopf bifurcation in the system. That is, there might by a way to define a scalar parameter in the system such that for this parameter within a range of values, the system exhibits a limit cycle.